# I cant access this in my foreach

Tags: codeigniter

heres the array structure but i dont know how to access it in foreach loop
but i dont know what im doing here
im so frustrated for almost twelve ours

```
Array
(
[30] => Array
    (
        [166] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [loan_id] => 166
                        [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
                        [loan_amount] => 5000
                        [loan_interest] => 5
                        [loan_total_amount] => 5250
                        [loan_collectables] => 2
                        [loan_user_id] => 30
                    )

                [82] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 81
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-26
                                [coll_amount] => 2625
                                [coll_loan_id] => 166
                                [coll_user_id] => 30
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 82
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                                [coll_amount] => 2625
                                [coll_loan_id] => 166
                                [coll_user_id] => 30
                            )

                    )

            )

        [167] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [loan_id] => 167
                        [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
                        [loan_amount] => 5000
                        [loan_interest] => 5
                        [loan_total_amount] => 5250
                        [loan_collectables] => 2
                        [loan_user_id] => 30
                    )

                [84] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 83
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                                [coll_amount] => 2625
                                [coll_loan_id] => 167
                                [coll_user_id] => 30
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 84
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                                [coll_amount] => 2625
                                [coll_loan_id] => 167
                                [coll_user_id] => 30
                            )

                    )

            )

        [168] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [loan_id] => 168
                        [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
                        [loan_amount] => 2121
                        [loan_interest] => 2
                        [loan_total_amount] => 2163
                        [loan_collectables] => 1
                        [loan_user_id] => 30
                    )

                [85] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 85
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-21
                                [coll_amount] => 2163
                                [coll_loan_id] => 168
                                [coll_user_id] => 30
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [169] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [loan_id] => 169
                        [loan_fullname] => Dy, Adrian Kim
                        [loan_amount] => 5000
                        [loan_interest] => 2
                        [loan_total_amount] => 5100
                        [loan_collectables] => 2
                        [loan_user_id] => 31
                    )

                [87] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 86
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                                [coll_amount] => 2550
                                [coll_loan_id] => 169
                                [coll_user_id] => 31
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [coll_id] => 87
                                [coll_date] => 2017-05-29
                                [coll_amount] => 2550
                                [coll_loan_id] => 169
                                [coll_user_id] => 31
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

heres my views but it says unidentified loan_id
in my foreach i dont know how to access the array with the array within the array of each element

```
                              <?php foreach($loans as $row) : ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?= $loans['loan_id'] ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <td class="text-center"></td>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </td>  
                                </tr>   
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

i dont know what to do..please help me ..im stuck here for almost 12 hours
how can i solve this?

```
Array
(
[166] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [loan_id] => 166
                [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
                [loan_amount] => 5000
                [loan_interest] => 5
                [loan_total_amount] => 5250
                [loan_collectables] => 2
                [loan_user_id] => 30
            )

        [82] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [coll_id] => 81
                        [coll_date] => 2017-05-26
                        [coll_amount] => 2625
                        [coll_loan_id] => 166
                        [coll_user_id] => 30
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [coll_id] => 82
                        [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                        [coll_amount] => 2625
                        [coll_loan_id] => 166
                        [coll_user_id] => 30
                    )

            )

    )

[167] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [loan_id] => 167
                [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
                [loan_amount] => 5000
                [loan_interest] => 5
                [loan_total_amount] => 5250
                [loan_collectables] => 2
                [loan_user_id] => 30
            )

        [84] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [coll_id] => 83
                        [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                        [coll_amount] => 2625
                        [coll_loan_id] => 167
                        [coll_user_id] => 30
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [coll_id] => 84
                        [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
                        [coll_amount] => 2625
                        [coll_loan_id] => 167
                        [coll_user_id] => 30
                    )

            )

    )

[168] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [loan_id] => 168
                [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
                [loan_amount] => 2121
                [loan_interest] => 2
                [loan_total_amount] => 2163
                [loan_collectables] => 1
                [loan_user_id] => 30
            )

        [85] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [coll_id] => 85
                        [coll_date] => 2017-05-21
                        [coll_amount] => 2163
                        [coll_loan_id] => 168
                        [coll_user_id] => 30
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: but still $row['loan_id'] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($loans as $key) {
    foreach ($key as $key1) {
        foreach ($key1 as $key2) {
            if(@$key2['loan_id'] != ''){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo @$key2['loan_id']; ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"></td>
                    <td class="text-center"></td>
                    <td class="text-center"></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <td class="text-center"></td>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```